# How many subsets of S contains A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $S$ of size $n$ and $A \subseteq S$ of size $k$, how many subsets of $S$ contain $A$?

I think it should be $2^{n} - 2^{n-k}$ ? Please tell is it correct or not ?

Comment: It is not.  For a correct approach, note that for each of the elements in $A$, we forcibly choose that they will be in each of the subsets we count.  For each of the remaining $n-k$ elements, we have two choices... it either is in the subset we are counting or it is not.

Comment: $2^n-2^{n-k}$ is the number of subsets of $S$ for which $A$ is *not* a subset.

Comment: Can you answer it @JMoravitz it would be helpful or can you just tell me what would be answer ?

Comment: I gave you more than enough information to answer it yourself

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: the number of subsets of $S\backslash A.$ You can figure out the number from this.

Comment: So it should be $2^{n-k}$